# disable key entry in pe:timePicker inside a p:datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, primefaces-extensions

How do I disable keyboard entry in a primefaces extensions timePicker inside a primefaces datatable ? There is no property by default like p:calendar.

Can i do it via js ?
I have to either disable keyboard entry or manipulate the component such that it hides the popup and the user can only type in values. Tried the latter using css but it failed. Please help.

Thanks !

Comment: have you found the solution for "disable key entry in <pe:timePicker>

Comment: No, I had raised an issue in the primefaces extensions issue tracker. They will probably add it at some point in the future. For now they suggested using javascript to achieve this, although i was unable to do so.

https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/issues/302

Comment: I'm trying to manage this with warnings when key pressed using 'keyup' event and <pe:keyfilter for="id" mask="num"/>  filter.thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware you can't do it on the component itself...YET.
What has worked for me with JSF regarding a similar issue was the Javascript/Jquery approach. For instance you take an Id or a class of certain component you want to disable the keyboard on and do the following.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#yourComponentId").keydown(false);
});
```

or this:

```
...
    $(".yourComponentClassname").on("keydown keypress keyup", false);
...
```

As far as I am aware if you give the component an attribute like:

```
... readonly = true ...
```

your backing bean will ignore it unless you mess around with:

```
FacesContext#getRenderResponse();
```

Hope this helps a bit.